# Context Manager Hackery

Tags: python, contextmanager

I'm trying to make a quick and dirty caching system for Python, using the trick that a context-manager can be made to conditionally skip the code in its context — see [Skipping execution of -with- block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12594789/851699).  I've stumbled upon a weird failure case of this and I was wondering if someone can help understand and fix this.

Before anyone says this, I know what I'm doing is terrible and I shouldn't do it, etc, etc.

Anyway, here is the code for the tricky context manager:

```
import sys
import inspect

class SkippableContext(object):

    def __init__(self,mode=0):
        """
        if mode = 0, proceed as normal
        if mode = 1, do not execute block
        """
        self.mode=mode

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.mode==1:
            print('   ... Skipping Context')
            # Do some magic
            sys.settrace(lambda *args, **keys: None)
            frame = inspect.currentframe(1)
            frame.f_trace = self.trace

        return 'SET BY TRICKY CONTEXT MANAGER!!'

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        raise

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        return True
```

And here is the test code:

```
print('==== First Pass with skipping disabled ====')

c='not set'
with SkippableContext(mode=0) as c:
    print('Should Get into here')
    c = 'set in context'
print('c: {}'.format(c))

print('==== Second Pass with skipping enabled ====')

c='not set'
with SkippableContext(mode=1) as c:
    print('This code is not printed')
    c = 'set in context'
print('c: {}'.format(c))

c='not set'
with SkippableContext(mode=1) as c:
    print('This code is not printed')
    c = 'set in context'
print('c: {}'.format(c))

print('==== Third Pass: Same as second pass but in a loop ====')

for i in range(2):
    c='not set'
    with SkippableContext(mode=1) as c:  # For some reason, assinging c fails on the second iteration!
        print('This code is not printed')
        c = 'set in context'
    print('c: {}'.format(c))
```

The output generated by the test code is as expected, except for the very last line, where `c` is not set:

```
==== First Pass with skipping disabled ====
Should Get into here
c: set in context
==== Second Pass with skipping enabled ====
   ... Skipping Context
c: SET BY TRICKY CONTEXT MANAGER!!
   ... Skipping Context
c: SET BY TRICKY CONTEXT MANAGER!!
==== Third Pass: Same as second pass but in a loop ====
   ... Skipping Context
c: SET BY TRICKY CONTEXT MANAGER!!
   ... Skipping Context
c: not set
```

Why is `c` not set in the second run of the loop?  Is there some hack to fix the bug in this hack?

Comment: What is the `1` passed at `inspect.currentframe(1)`? I'm not seeing `currentFrame` taking any arguments.

Comment: That's for "1 step up in the stack" - ie. the frame of the caller of the context manager.

Comment: Weird. I can't find a single doc reference to a function `inspect.currentframe` that takes an argument. This doesn't run for me in IntelliJ. I just wanted to play around with it. That answer is in Python 2 seemingly, but even the 2.7 docs show it without any parameters.

Comment: When I execute your test code, on the _second pass_, the result is: `TypeError: currentframe() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` — so it never even gets to the loop.

Comment: Ya, I'm not sure what `inspect` this is expecting.

Comment: AFAIK, `frame = sys._getframe(1)` would do the right thing — but that doesn't fix/explain the loop issue.

Comment: To make things clear for everyone, **in  *Python 2* (even in *.7.16*), `inspect.currentframe` is defined as `sys._getframe`** (although the doc doesn't reflect it). Also, the behavior can be generalized: when increasing the loop steps, the even (*0* based) iterations would yield `SET BY TRICKY CONTEXT MANAGER!!` while odd ones would yield `not set`.

Comment: For anyone crawling down this rabbithole in the future, I ended up abandoning this approach in favour of of something only slightly less hacky: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58647294/851699

Comment: You may be interested in a very similar edge case where the `as` variable is not accessible after the context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594148/skipping-execution-of-with-block#comment104091057_54765496

Answer (score 4):

The awful hack you're using does a lot of things with nasty, subtle consequences. I doubt the author fully understood it (if they did, they wouldn't have used a bare `raise`, and they wouldn't have tried to pass `inspect.currentframe` an argument it doesn't take). Incidentally, the incorrect usage of `inspect.currentframe` causes the code to fail with a `TypeError` instead of doing what you describe, so for the rest of this answer, I'll assume that call is replaced with `sys._getframe(1)`, which produces the described behavior.

---

One of the things the hack relies on is setting a *local trace function* with `frame.f_trace = self.trace`. This local trace function will raise an exception on the first line inside the `with` block... or at least, that's what it normally does.

Python calls trace functions when certain *trace events* happen. One of those trace events is the start of a new source line. Python determines that a new source line has started by checking whether the current bytecode instruction index corresponds to either the first instruction of a line, or an instruction at an index prior to the last instruction executed. You can see that in [`maybe_call_line_trace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/ceval.c#L4276) in `Python/ceval.c`.

Python only updates `instr_prev`, the variable used to determine the last instruction executed, when tracing is active. However, once the local trace function raises an exception, it is automatically deactivated, and `instr_prev` stops receiving updates.

When the local trace function is set, the next two instructions it could activate on are the `STORE_NAME` to set `c` (or `STORE_FAST` if you put the code in a function), and the `LOAD_NAME` to load the `print` function for the next line (or `LOAD_GLOBAL` if you put the code in a function).

The first time through the loop, it activates on `LOAD_NAME`, and `instr_prev` is set to that instruction's index. The local trace function is then disabled, because it raised an exception.

The second time through the loop, `instr_prev` is still set to the index of the `LOAD_NAME`, so Python thinks the `STORE_NAME` marks the beginning of a new line. The local trace function activates on `STORE_NAME`, and the exception prevents the assignment to `c`.

You can see the instructions where the local trace function activates by inspecting `frame.f_lasti` in `trace`, and comparing the results to the instruction indices in the output of `dis.dis`. For example, the following variant of your code:

```
import sys
import inspect
import dis

class SkippableContext(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('   ... Skipping Context')
        sys.settrace(lambda *args, **keys: None)
        frame = sys._getframe(1)
        frame.f_trace = self.trace
        return 'SET BY TRICKY CONTEXT MANAGER!!'

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        print(frame.f_lasti)
        raise Exception

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        return True

def f():
    for i in range(2):
        c='not set'
        with SkippableContext() as c:
            print('This code is not printed')
            c = 'set in context'
        print('c: {}'.format(c))

f()
dis.dis(f)
```

produces the following output:

```
   ... Skipping Context
26
c: SET BY TRICKY CONTEXT MANAGER!!
   ... Skipping Context
24
c: not set
 21           0 SETUP_LOOP              64 (to 66)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                52 (to 64)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 22          14 LOAD_CONST               2 ('not set')
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (c)

 23          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (SkippableContext)
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             22 SETUP_WITH              18 (to 42)
             24 STORE_FAST               1 (c)

 24          26 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             28 LOAD_CONST               3 ('This code is not printed')
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             32 POP_TOP

 25          34 LOAD_CONST               4 ('set in context')
             36 STORE_FAST               1 (c)
             38 POP_BLOCK
             40 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
        >>   42 WITH_CLEANUP_START
             44 WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH
             46 END_FINALLY

 26          48 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (print)
             50 LOAD_CONST               5 ('c: {}')
             52 LOAD_METHOD              3 (format)
             54 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
             56 CALL_METHOD              1
             58 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             60 POP_TOP
             62 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   64 POP_BLOCK
        >>   66 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             68 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `26` printed the first time corresponds to the index of the `LOAD_GLOBAL`, and the `24` printed the second time corresponds to the index of the `STORE_FAST`.

Comment: The article is years old, from *Python 2* "era", where `inspect.currentframe(level)` was *OK*, even if not documented (check my comment to the question).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.  I think I understand the mechanism now.  This also made me notice that it will actually skip the `as c:` on odd iterations, not just after the first.   I'll see if I can use this to find a solution or at least detect the loop case and raise an exception.