# Conditionally skipping the body of Python With statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `With` statement that I'd like to skip if some `<condition>` is satisfied. That is, I write:

```
With MyContext() as mc:
  do_something()
```

and

```
class MyContext(object):
...
def __enter__(self,...):
  if <condition>:
    JumpToExit()
def __exit__(self,...):
  print('goodbye')
```

I would like `do_something()` to be executed only on certain conditions, otherwise I'd like `JumpToExit()` to skip the body entirely and just finish the block.

Thanks.

Comment: Or this: [Skipping execution of -with- block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594148/skipping-execution-of-with-block)

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. A with statement cannot cancel the block. However, you could do something like this:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return condition
```

Then, when you use the context:

```
with context as condition:
    if condition:
        ....
```

If you want to return something else as well you can return a tuple like `return condition, self` then to use it you can unpack the tuple like `with condition, context:`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that is possible. `__enter__` is executed outside of the `try` block introduced by the `with` statement, so I don't see a way of jumping directly from `__enter__` into `__exit__`.

`with` basically (simplified) turns this:

```
with context as x:
    do_something()
```

Into

```
x = context.__enter__()
try:
    do_something()
finally:
    context.__exit__()
```

You need to throw an exception in `do_something()` or successfully complete it to get into `__exit__`. If you do throw an exception from `do_something()` you can do tricky stuff like suppressing it in the **exit** function (using some of the parameters passed to it), so you don't actually see it. But it has to be the code inside the `with` block which somehow causes the jump into `__exit__`.

Maybe if you can somehow ensure that `do_something` immediately throws an exception by setting some value in `__enter__` you can make it work. But that does not sound like a very good idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the with statement in a function and use return:

```
def foo():
    With MyContext() as mc:
        if <condition>:
            return None
        do_something()
```