# Acquire a multiprocessing.Lock in a with statement if non-blocking or with timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

With a normal `multiprocessing.Lock` (or `threading.Lock`) you can simplify the following code:

```py
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
```

```py
lock.acquire()

try:
    ...
finally:
    lock.release()
```

into:

```py
with lock:
    ...
```

However, can I still use a context manager when I want to pass some arguments to `lock.acquire(...)`, such as `block=` or `timeout=`? For example, I have code like this:

```py
lock_success = lock.acquire(block=False)

if not lock_success:
    return

try:
    ...
finally:
    lock.release()
```

I don't see a way to pass this argument to the context manager (since it's in the `acquire` call and not the constructor).

(The idea is that the `with`-block would get skipped if the lock cannot be acquired.)

Analogously for `threading.Lock` which provides a similar API.

Comment: not great to release a lock unless `lock_success = True`...

Comment: If you need a timeout on locking a `Lock`, then IMO that's a strong code smell. Either you could choose a more appropriate type of object (e.g., a queue, or a semaphore, or a barrier, or...) to coordinate the activity of your threads, or else you could re-structure your code so that no thread ever needs to keep a `Lock` locked for long enough to impact the performance of other threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I disagree... For the sake of avoiding deadlock, I would say it is bad practice to not have a timeout. (though I would typically raise an error at timeout If I expect it to usually acquire in a fairly consistent amount of time rather than continuing) I suppose it depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but if it's peak performance you're after, you're not using python anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; you cannot use the built-in lock context manager, but it can still be done fairly cleanly.

It could almost work because `Lock.__enter__()` does return the value returned from the call to `acquire()` which should be the boolean success or failure of getting the lock.

```py
l = Lock()
with l as success:
    if success:
        print("run some code")
    else:
        print("skip the code")
```

Frustratingly however it is not possible to pass arguments to the internal call to `acquire` (hardcoded args [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c#L680)). I would recommend writing your own context manager to solve this, as it is quite straightforward:

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def get_lock(lock, block=True, timeout=None):
    held = lock.acquire(block=block, timeout=timeout)
    try:
        yield held
    finally:
        if held:
            lock.release()

#### example usage ####

l = Lock()
#lock should be acquired so success == True
with get_lock(l) as success:
    if success:
        print("run some code")
    else:
        print("skip the code")

l.acquire()
#lock won't be acquired and block will proceed after timeout
#use the value of success to determine what to do
with get_lock(l, True, 3) as success:
    if success:
        print("run some code")
    else:
        print("skip the code")

l.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that this is not possible because of how context managers are designed in Python. What happens with a context manager (CM) is:

```py
with CM:
    ...
```

- The CM's `__enter__` method is called
- The block inside of `with` is run
- The CM's `__exit__` method is called

Thus there is no way to "skip" the inside of the `with`-block, so I guess this explains the design of the `Lock` class. Although there are some [dark magic ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12594789/2111778) around that (which should be avoided).